# Imprimir dos consultas en un mismo "td" o "select"

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

buenos días, estoy realizando un CRUD, y ahora mismo estoy realizando una tabla en la que poder seleccionar modificar o insertar usuarios, bueno llego a la conclusión, de que cuando le paso la tabla a los usuarios ellos eligen por ejemplo que usuario quieren seleccionar, pero solo pueden seleccionar el acronimo, pero claro quisiera que seleccionaran el acronimo de sus nombres pero que al lado o superpuesto se pueda visualizar que nombre y que apellidos le corresponden a ese acronimo.

Este es el codigo que tengo para seleccionar los acronimos ahora mismo, solo necesito imprimir al lado o superpuesto el nombre mas apellidos que estan en la misma tabla que el acronimo.

```
<td>
    <select id="acro_usuario1" name="acro_usuario1">
            <option value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('acro_usuario') : ''; ?>"><?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('acro_usuario') : ''; ?> </option>    
            <?php
            $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=deimos1', 'root', '');
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare('Select acro_usuario from usuarios'); 
            $stmt->execute();
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                   echo '<option>' . $row['acro_usuario'] . '</option>';
            }
            ?>
     </select>
</td>
```

Comment: ¿Has intentado solventarlo de alguna manera? Igual no he entendido bien la pregunta pero sinceramente, no me creo que si has desarrollado ese código no sepas hacer lo que pides... ¿Puedes poner más info de la tabla "usuarios" para conocer el nombre de los campos que se han de usar?

Comment: Los campos son (`acro_usuario``nombre``apellidos``departamento``email`) , pero claro, no se si me estoy liando, pero deberia ser una consulta del tipo:"select nombre,apellidos from usuarios where acro_usuario = acro_usuario" pero el where es la parte en la que fallo porque debo de obtener el dato y digo que no lo recojo bien

Comment: Vale, ahora sí queda más claro. Entiendo que el valor de `$obj_categoria->__GET('acro_usuario')` es correcto y no está vacío ni nada. Debes usar este valor como valor a comprar en el `where`.

Comment: " $stmt = $pdo->prepare('Select nombre,apellidos from usuarios where acro_usuario = $obj_categoria->__GET('acro_usuario') '); "  Asi seria la linea debajo de la otra ocnsulta?

Comment: El valor debe ser tratado como una variable no como un string, por lo que tienes que cerrar el string despues del "= " y concanetar el valor: `$stmt = $pdo->prepare('select acro_usuario from usuarios where acro_usuario = "' . $obj_categoria->__GET('acro_usuario') . '";');`. Revisa un poco la sentencia que la he puesto a ojo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que debes hacer es poner en el interior de las etiquetas `<option>` el texto que quieras que vean los usuarios y en el atributo `value` el valor que quieras que se mande con el formulario.

Es importante que todos los datos pasen por la función [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) para que los caracteres que puedan ser confundidos con caracteres especiales HTML sean sustituidos por sus entidades HTML (`<`, `>`, `"`, `'` y `&`).

Ejemplo:

```
<td>
    <select id="acro_usuario1" name="acro_usuario1">
            <option value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('acro_usuario') : ''; ?>"><?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('acro_usuario') : ''; ?> </option>    
            <?php
            $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=deimos1', 'root', '');
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare('Select acro_usuario from usuarios'); 
            $stmt->execute();
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                   echo '<option name="' .
                     htmlspecialchars($row['acro_usuario']) . '">' .
                     htmlspecialchars(
                       $row['acro_usuario'] . '(' .
                       $row['nombre'] . ' ' .
                       $row['apellidos'] . ')'
                     ) . '</option>';
            }
            ?>
     </select>
</td>
```

Dependiendo del método usado en el formulario, el valor de `acro_usuario` seleccionado te llegará como `$_GET['acro_usuario1']` o `$_POST['acro_usuario1']` (en general, pero desaconsejado, `$_REQUEST['acro_usuario1']`).

Comment: Perfecto esto era lo que queria. el metodo es por POST. El select muestra los acronimo de tal manera, tu nombre por ejemplo, Oscar Garcia ->OG pues el select muestra OG ( ) y dentro del parentesis no indica los nombres pero si deja el espacio mirare por is es error de variables o algo. Muchisimas gracias.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que he puesto los índices "a ciegas" sin saber cuáles son realmente en la base de datos. Fíjate que es sensible a mayúsculas/minúsculas. Usa `var_dump($row)` si quieres saber con exactitud el nombre de los campos que debes usar.

Comment: calla calla que al no copiar por que eso no te vale de nada si no, que lo e hecho yo por mi cuenta una vez e visto tu codigo tube un error de sintaxis en una coma, cosa que por h o por b las comas y yo no somos buenos compañeros jajajaja. Muchisimas gracias por tu aydua funciona a la perfeccion!